# Could you clarify these statements regarding depth in a mix

Tags: mixing, acoustics

I'm trying to establish the correct formula for these settings if you guys could correct them. It is imperative you're 100% sure of the answer as this plays a vital piece in my understanding of reverb.

*If a sound source is close to the listener but the room is big..*

**that would mean the instrument is loud in the mix but the early reflections are low in the mix.**

*If a sound source is far from the listener and the room is big..*

**that would mean both the instrument and early reflections would have to be low in the mix.**

*If a sound source is close to the listener but the room is small..*

**that would mean the instrument is loud in the mix and the early reflections are loud in the mix.**

*If a sound source is far from the listener and the room is small..*

**that would mean the instrument is low in the mix but the early reflections are loud in the mix**

---

Are these statements correct and if not could you correct them in stated format?

From what i read, "a bigger room will have its surfaces farher away from the listener and thus bounced reflections will travel longer distances and be quieter." although i've also read to use more or louder reverb to give the perception of distance, so im confused..

Thank you guys!

Comment: All those seem to be logical.

Comment: The approach makes sense, but there's more to this than levels. The usual way to achieve depth is to manipulate the pre-delay. Mixers often have 2 or 3 reverbs set up with different pre-delay times. Just altering the levels of reflections will be less effective.